Smoothly transition SVG elements with the view transition API
I have the following problem: I am trying to move SVG elements with the view transition API smoothly from one position to the other by applying a view-transition-name. While this works perfectly for HTML elements for some reason only the default cross-fade animation is applied to SVG elements.
In the demo you see two elements: a circle rendered with SVG and a square rendered with HTML. When the SVG circle is clicked the default animation, the cross-fade, is applied. When the HTML square is clicked a smooth transition is performed. Both examples have more or less the same config: startViewTransition is called, the element is replaced with the same ID as before. Shouldn't that smooth transition also work for SVG elements, am I doing something wrong in my demo or did I miss something?
I know that the smooth transition for SVGs can be achieved by customizing the animation with the web animations API for example, but I'd like to get that working with the view-transition-name only.
Unfortunately this demo only works in Chromium-based browsers at the moment.
Demo - also on CodePen


document.getElementById("svg").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.startViewTransition(() => {
    // Update DOM for the second state
    document.getElementById("svg").innerHTML = `
          <circle id="icon" style="transform: translate(100px, 100px);" r="40" fill="red" />
  `;
  });
});

document.getElementById("second").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.startViewTransition(() => {
    document.getElementById(
      "second"
    ).innerHTML = `<div id="item" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: blue; position: absolute; transform: translate(200px, 200px);"></div>`;
  });
});
icon {
  view-transition-name: icon;
}

#second {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

#item {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  view-transition-name: item;
}
<div id="first">
  <svg 
    id="svg" 
    viewBox="0 0 100 100" 
    style="width: 100px; height: 100px">
        <circle id="icon" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="blue" />
  </svg>
</div>
<div id="second">
  <div id="item"></div>
</div>




The transition API is relatively new and doesn't provide a reliable cross-browser rendering. In other words: better opt for a CSS or JS property animation concept. Highly subjective: I doubt the API will ever become the ultimate transition concept covering all properties for smooth animations. So a cross-fade is the best you can get for SVG elements.
